# What is this "in app browser" called and how do I disable it

Tags: nexus-5, browser, 7.0-nougat

I factory reset my Nexus 5x a few days ago and ever since most apps (if not all) are opening all links in this in-app, stripped down, reading mode browser. Before the reset I'd never seen this:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't have any onward journey or sharing button so I can't open in a real browser (for eg if it is required) so it is supremely useless.

And I don't know what it's called so I can't figure out how to just open links in chrome.

Can anyone help?

Comment: See if updating  [Android system web view](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) helps

Comment: I think since I'm on android 7 system web view is disabled and cannot be enabled (that's certainly the case the play store and I think I'd correct)

Comment: I think I read something about Chrome handling WebViews on Nougat with is custom tabs feature. Do you have Chrome installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was webview. I used http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ to check.

Even though webview showed as disabled.

I factory reset a second time and it stopped using that browser

> ¯_(ツ)_/¯